# How to denormalized data in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table that has Clinic Names and Doctor Names.  one clinic can have many doctors.  I need to split this data into two tables.  one with clinic info and the other with Doctor info

trying to do this in a SQL query

Table CLINIC_DOC:

```
ID  ClinicName  Doctor
------------------------
1   xyz         Dr Joe
2   xyz         Dr Bob
3   abc         Dr Mary
4   abc         Dr John
```

I want to split the data into the following tables like this:

Table ClinicsData:

```
ClinicID    ClinicName
----------------------
1           xyz
2           abc
```

Table DoctorData:

```
DocId   ClinicID    Doctor
--------------------------
1       1           Dr Joe
2       1           Dr Bob
3       2           Dr Mary
4       2           Dr John
```

Comment: This isn't possible because your source table does not define a primary key for Clinics, only Doctors. How do we know clinic `abc` is meant to have `ClinicID = 2`?

Comment: @Dai That's why you build and populate ClinicsData first with ClinicsID as an identity column. Then you can use ClinicsData to populate DotorData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the ID columns (`ClinicID` and `DocID`) are automatically generated and that the clinic names are unique (i.e there are no two clinics with the same name in the portion of the real world your data represents) you can try:

```
INSERT INTO clinicsdata
            (clinicname)
            SELECT DISTINCT
                   cd.clinicname
                   FROM clinic_doc cd;

INSERT INTO doctordata
            (clinicid,
             doctor)
            SELECT c.clinicid,
                   cd.doctor
                   FROM clinic_doc cd
                        INNER JOIN clinicsdata c
                                   ON c.clinicname = cd.clinicname;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll probably want to create the tables you're going to populate. Here's my best guess at dataypes:

```
CREATE TABLE ClinicsData
(
    ClinicID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ClinicName varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE DoctorData
(
    DocID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ClinicID INT,
    Doctor VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Notice that I've made `ClinicsData.ClinicID` an `IDENTITY` column. This will help us to populate `DoctorData` later.

Next, let's populate `ClinicsData` with all the distinct clinic names.

```
INSERT INTO ClinicsData
(
    ClinicName
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ClinicName 
FROM CLINIC_DOC;
```

Now, we can utilize `ClinicsData` to populate `DoctorData`, using an `INNER JOIN`.

```
INSERT INTO DoctorData
(
    ClinicID
    ,Doctor
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    cd.ClinicID,
    c_d.Doctor
FROM CLINIC_DOC c_d
INNER JOIN ClinicsData cd ON cd.ClinicName = c_d.ClinicName
```